# What difference it makes when using ' /<int:id>' instead of '/<slug>' in url-patterns(Django)? Which method is more preferable?

Tags: python, django, url

I want to use URL-pattern to fetch product view from my products list. But I came across two methods and a bit confused about which to select.
     1)`<slug>`
     2) `<int:id>`

Comment: I think it depends on your use case. If you want to give a search/get view by product name functionality at this URL `<slug>` is the way to go. If you only want to get product by id, there's no point parsing a slug value to get `int`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it @KshitijSaxena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) for the url patterns. The two patterns you are comparing are very different:

1. `<slug>` could also be just `<something>`. It's just the name of the variable you want to capture, because you didn't include a path converter. By default, this could be any string (excluding the path separator `'/'`).
2. `<int:id>` specifies two things: A path converter (`int`) and the variable name (`id`) that you want to capture. In this case, only URLs where this part is integer will match the pattern. `id` will always be an integer.

If you read the documentation, you'll see that you could also use the `slug` path converter, e.g. `<slug:slug>` so this will match a subset of strings (ASCII, numbers, hyphens and underscores) and call the captured variable `slug`.

The captured variables are passed to your view. So if you want to make a product detail view by passing the product id in the url, you should use `<int:id>` and in your view the variable `id` can be used to fetch the corresponding product. But if your product model has a slug field and you prefer using that (a slugified version of the product name, e.g. "sweater-men-with-front-logo") then use `<slug:slug>`.